# Блочная вёрстка, позиции блоков и их содержимое

Tags: html, css

Если не указываю высоту блока то содержимое выходит за его границы. Как сделать так, чтобы высота выставлялась автоматически в зависимости от количества содержимого? Значение auto не помогает.

Comment: Дай пример кода пожалуйста, может накосячил просто где.

Comment: в таких случаях нужно всегда включать демо (jsfiddle, к примеру). Много других CSS свойств играет роль: `position`, `float` и т. п. Поэтому без конкретного примера - это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 1):

задайте блоку ,тому в котором контент, `float:left`. за частую блоки так себя ведут,когда у родительского уже стоит обтекание и это исправляется все тем же обтеканием